# one post into an iframe in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe

in wordpress how can I load an one post into lightbox iframe, like  [www.wookmark.com](http://wookmark.com), when click on details and opening the lightbox with post and related posts. I did so, in lndex.php I set the loop `<?php the_content();?>` then in that loop I write the second `<?php the_content();?>` which made dabsolute and display none, then with javascript I am callling the div with second `<?php the_content();?>` and appears the post...but I want the post as in single.php, I mean that navigation links in it open the next post in iframe and not in main page, I have also tried to call iframe putting in it  in that case the whole single.php loaded in iframe, with header, footer and navigatin menu, but I just want only the content, how can I relazie that,?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question, but if you want your posts to display in home page like in www.wookmark.com you can use 
[query post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: no, I mean when you click on "details" there open a lightbox window with that image and with similiar images in right side, and when click on the rigth right similiars photos, they are opening in the same lightbox window..here are the screenshots explaining what I mean

Step one .http://db.tt/aWyLA1yi    
Step two.http://db.tt/OZryKSEN

how can I relaze like this?

Comment: Using plugins are the best option, here is a premium plugin http://codecanyon.net/item/soapbox-gallery-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/2553396 hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you, but I can't find how it can help me, clicking on the thumbnails it is not opening the full image with arrows to next image and its smiliars images in the side